# Wordpress error on saving administration settings with IDN domains

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service, idn

I have created a new wordpress site on Azure Web Sites, this time using IDN Domain. I configured the domain in the administrator page using its punycode representation:

Wordpress URL: http://xn--sandraeiaki-8db.com
Site URL: http://xn--sandraeiaki-8db.com

Everything works fine, except saving settings from the worpress settings page inside the administration. After successfully saving settings wordpress tries to redirect back to the settings page, however somehow that redirect changes the domain, instead of redirecting back to http://xn--sandraeiaki-8db.com it redirects to http://xn--sandraeiaki-bra36d.com/

The only clue I got is that, http://xn--sandraeiaki-bra36d.com/ is the punycode representation of http://sandraeiã±aki.com/, so it seems like wordpress is using an invalid encoding here instead of UTF-8 for redirecting back to the settings page.

**Update**

I can see in wordpress options.php file that it tries to redirect using, after succesfully saving changes:

```
/**
* Redirect back to the settings page that was submitted
*/
$goback = add_query_arg( 'settings-updated', 'true',  wp_get_referer() );
wp_redirect( $goback );
exit;
```

**Update 2**
After a chat session with **soulseekah** we have traced back the issue to be in the location value set by IIS on Azure, creating a simple php page, that changes the location header, the redirection fails:

`<?php header( 'Location: /' ); exit; ?>`

Examining the location header value, shows that it is encoded in ASCII instead of UTF-8:

> Location: sandraeiÃ±aki.com

**Update 3**

After some testing it only happens when the header() php function is passed a relative location url value, setting the location value to an absolute uri resolves without problems , either by using the punycode domain encoding or utf-8 encoding.

I made a temporaly fix by changing wordpress redirect function, now it sets only absolute uris, and seems to be working.

However, how I can fix that behaviour permanently?

Comment: What version of WordPress are you using? Is there a real Location redirect? Or a POST to the incorrect domain? Try searching for similar filed issues over at http://core.trac.wordpress.org/

Comment: Hi soulseekah, it's version 3.8, I also tried on the latest 3.7 version with the same results. I cannot find anything related on core.trac. What do you mean about a real Location redirect?

Comment: Ok, posted on Server Fault: http://serverfault.com/questions/561652/wordpress-error-on-saving-administration-settings-with-idn-domains

Comment: I mean you need to state what exactly is happening. There are different kinds of "redirecting back". Is it a real redirect, as in a "Location:" header? Or is it the result of a POST request gone wrong? I don't think this is off topic.

Comment: Yeah I don't think to, as most of the resolutions with this type of domains involved some programming fixes.

Comment: As I can see in options.php code, after saving settings, wordpres redirects using: wp_redirect I´ve updated the question to show the redirection code

Comment: Interesting and what is `wp_get_refer()` when you `var_dump` it?

Comment: It just returns the relative path to the options.php page: "/wp-admin/options-general.php"

Comment: And you're saying this does not happen when you save a post, for example?

Comment: No it does not happen when saving a post. Also checking the code on wp_redirect it does only call to header, setting a location header, to "/wp-admin/options-general.php?settings-updated=true" it does not look like anywhere is setting the host name.

Comment: I think I found it, when saving a post wp_redirect set a location header with the full domain name in punycode "http://xn--sandraeiaki-8db.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=1&action=edit&message=1" The settings page does not do that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43279/discussion-between-soulseekah-and-ice)